# scss mixin for custom css properties

Tags: css, sass, mixins

```
@mixin genericSidesStyles ($sides, $style, $cssProperty) {
  @if($sides == '') {
    $cssProperty: $style;
  }
  @else {
    @each $side in $sides {
      @if ($side == 'top' or $side == 'bottom' or $side == 'left' or $side == 'right' ) {
         $cssProperty-#{$side}: $style;
       }
     }
  }
}
```

This is a scss mixin for giving styles to css properties with sides like margin, padding, border etc.

I am calling my mixin as below

```
@include genericSidesStyles('top', 20px, 'margin');
```

here top is for margin-top, 20px is the distance and margin is the cssProperty but I am getting the following error

> expected ':' after $cssProperty- in assignment statement

Help me to know where I am wrong in this

Comment: I tested your mixin, it seems its not passing the `@if ($side == 'top' or $side == 'bottom' or $side == 'left' or $side == 'right' )` condition. Remove the `@each` loop (not sure why is it even required) & it should work fine. Also change your statement to `#{$cssProperty}-#{$side}: $style`

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa I believe the loop is to allow for multiple $sides so properties for margin-top and margin-bottom can be created simultaneously by passing both values as a list for $sides.

Comment: It should start working now that you have edited your answer by removing `$cssProperty` from `@each` statement - All you need to do is change the statement `$cssProperty-#{$side}: $style;` to `#{$cssProperty}-#{$side}: $style;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to interpolate the `$cssProperty` variable (so it becomes `#{$cssProperty}`, just like you have done with the `$side` variable. So your final code should be:

```
@mixin genericSidesStyles ($sides, $style, $cssProperty) {
  @if($sides == '') {
    #{$cssProperty}: $style;
  }
  @else {
    @each $cssProperty, $side in $sides {
      @if ($side == 'top' or $side == 'bottom' or $side == 'left' or $side == 'right' ) {
         #{$cssProperty}-#{$side}: $style;
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks edmund but there is no need for cssProperty in @each line i posted it by mistake thanks for your help